ConfigureAwait(false) causing slow downs
This is a .NET 9 WPF project and as far as I know when awaiting Tasks ConfigureAwait(false) extension should be used here.
The Voltage property binds to a sliders Value.
FireAndForgetSafeAsync also uses ConfigureAwait(false) internally.
    public float Voltage
    {
        get => _voltage;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _voltage, value))
            {
                VoltageErrorState.ResetError();
                DebounceAndExecuteVoltageCommand(value).FireAndForgetSafeAsync(HandleError);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task DebounceAndExecuteVoltageCommand(float newValue)
    {
        bool debounced = await _voltageDebounce.DebounceAsync(250).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!debounced)
            return;

        await _voltageCommand.ExecuteAsync(newValue);
    }

public class Debouncer
{
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;

    public async Task<bool> DebounceAsync(int delayMilliseconds)
    {
        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await Task.Delay(delayMilliseconds, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

However when running the application in Debug mode slow downs are noticeable if the slider is moved constantly (the command is not triggered because of the debouncer). If I remove the ConfigureAwait(false) call inside the Debouncer class, the slider can be moved much smoother. The slow downs are only noticeable in Debug mode not in Release mode.
Am I using ConfigureAwait wrong here?
Is it sufficient to just use ConfigureAwait(false) in the setter?

What happens if you replace await _voltageCommand.ExecuteAsync(newValue);} with } await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);? Does the slow down happen in debug when compared with release?

Random thought but do you get a ton of caught exceptions in your debug window as you move the slider? Those can slow down the application significantly in debug mode but not in release. Second thought, ConfigureAwait(false) is really overrated and usually unnecessary. It really only matters if what comes after the await is likely to be both slow and synchronous. On the downside it can lead to excessive dispatcher posting or even unexpected threading errors if you have something after the await that needs to be done on the UI thread. Which is what might be happening here.
